# matplotlib doesn't show graph after opencv window

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, sublimetext

I need to plot data from an image. I use matplotlib.
But after running the command `cv2.imshow ('frame', frame)` matplotlib window crashes.

Here is my code with a while loop where I am processing the image. After processing, I close all windows and want to plot a graph.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Leo.gif', 0)


M = [] #среднее
Var = [] #дисперсия
Std = [] #среднеквадратичное отклонение

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()

  if not ret:
    break

  grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
  cv2.imshow('frame',grayFrame)

  M.append(np.mean(grayFrame[3]))
  Var.append(np.var(grayFrame[3], ddof=1)) 
  Std.append(np.std(grayFrame[3], ddof=1)) 

  if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff == ord('q'):
    break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

The program shows a gif, and then it interrupts.
When I run it from Sublime Text, it displays the message:

> [Finished in 2.1s with exit code -11] [cmd: ['python3', '-u',
> '/home/lala/RobotPainter/Projects/Start/gif_up.py']] [dir:
> /home/lala/RobotPainter/Projects/Start] [path:
> /home/lala/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]

When i run from terminal:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I realized that the error appears when executing the command: `plt.show()`

But when I comment  the line with : `cv2.imshow('frame',grayFrame)`
I get a graph

And when I first try to display the graph, and then go to the main while loop, the graph is displayed, and then the image is displayed

There is some relationship between `cv2.imshow('frame',grayFrame) and plt.show()`, which does not display the graph for me after the image is displayed.

How to plot the graph after viewing the image?

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue with interactive plotting from Jupyter lab. The image shows, goes away, and then the plot is displayed `python 3.8.11`, `cv2 4.0.1`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`. So maybe this is an environment / configuration issue.

Comment: @trenton-mckinney Thanks a lot for your comment and hints on the question. I ran this code in Jupyter lab and it worked correctly for me too. Let's work further!

Comment: I'm glad it works in that environment for you. I have no experience with Sublime, so I won't be able to help with that environment. I added sublimetext as a tag, but there are tags for specific versions, so you may want to update the tag.